# Redirect all php extension to none extension with .htaccess

Tags: php, redirect

I have set a rule to remove php extension now I want to redirect url with php extension to url without php extension

EX: `mysite.com/test.php redirect to mysite.com/test` 
    `mysite.com/test.php? redirect to mysite.com/test?`
    `mysite.com/test.php# redirect to mysite.com/test#`

I have lots of php page so I want a rule for all pages and my php pages generate dynamic URL also.

Thanks

Comment: What webserver are you talking about? Apache?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Apache,

You can use following;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And be sure that above rule, will respond 404 if file not exists, or it is a directory.

When you type `domain.com/tes` this will be act `domain.com/test.php` at backend.

If you want to redirect user when he uses `domain.com/test.php` to `domain.com/test` you can use;

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Yup, that should do it. If you want to learn more check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html and also http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Answer (score -1):

If Apache, then In your Virtual host directory of Apache settings you need to add following code

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

And then restart Apache, in this case you don't have to redirect each page

Comment: Sorry dude, this won't do any thing, you need to use mod_rewrite in order to achieve what's been asked.